# x,y point shifts when the width is reduced below 200 in QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qt4

I have created a QGraphicsScene

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,200,200);
```

and draw a line `scene.addLine(0,0,100,100,pen);` and I got the line correctly drawn from (0,0) to (100,100).

When I change the code to

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,150,200);
```

And draw the same line `scene.addLine(0,0,100,100,pen);,` Its x,y point shifts to the right side by 50 pixels. Why does this happen? How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the scene rectangle is centered in the `QGraphicsView` when it is smaller than the view.

You can use `QGraphicsView::setAlignment` to change that.

---

Since the view preferred size, returned by `QGraphicsView::sizeHint()` is also the scene size, you can adjust the view to fit exactly the scene with:

```
view->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

which tells the layout to only use `sizeHint()` to calculate the size of the widget.

Or if the view is not inside a layout, you'll have to set the size with

```
view->setFixedSize(view->sizeHint());
```

each time you change the scene rect size.

Comment: when I align left, the line seems to be correctly drawn. But the width of the view is still 200, not 150. How to make it 150?